# Laravel : ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to a member function getAvatar() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I already create 3 models objects : User.php, Post.php, DataPribadi.php

This is User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
     use Notifiable;
     
     public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function datapribadi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DataPribadi::class);
    }
}
```

This is Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is DataPribadi.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DataPribadi extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'datapribadi';
    protected $fillable = ['namalengkap','namapanggilan','tempatlahir','tgllahir','jeniskelamin','golongandarah','namaayah','namaibu','avatar','user_id'];

    public function getAvatar()
    {
        if(!$this->Avatar){
            return asset('images/default.jpg');
        }

        return asset('images/'.$this->Avatar);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is DataPribadiController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\DataPribadiExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use PDF;
use App\DataPribadi;


//use App\Http\Requests;

class DataPribadiController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        #ini untuk ambil data yang masuk di variable $request
        #dd($request->all());

        #untuk search
        if($request->has('cari')){
            $data_datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::where('NamaLengkap','LIKE','%'.$request->cari.'%')->get();
        }else{
            #untuk tampilkan data
            $data_datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::all(); #INI TAMBAHKAN WHERE ISACTIVE = 1
        }
        return view ('datapribadi.index',['data_datapribadi' => $data_datapribadi]);
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {  
        $this->validate($request,[
            'namalengkap' => 'required|min:5',
            'namapanggilan' => 'required|min:5',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'tempatlahir' => 'required',
            'tgllahir' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'golongandarah' => 'required',
            'namaayah' => 'required|min:5',
            'namaibu' => 'required|min:5',
            'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|dimensions:max_width=400,max_height=400,min_width=100,min_height=100'
        ]);
        
        #untuk insert user
        $user = new \App\User;
        $user->role = 'jemaat';
        $user->name = $request->namalengkap;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt('jemaat');
        $user->remember_token = str_random(60);
        $user->save();

        #untuk insert datapribadi
        $request->request->add(['user_id' => $user->id ]);
        $datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::create($request->all());
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $request->file('avatar')->move('images',$request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName());
            $datapribadi->avatar = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
            $datapribadi->save();
        }

        return redirect('/datapribadi')->with('sukses','Data berhasil diinput');
    }

    public function edit(DataPribadi $datapribadi)
    {
        #untuk ambil data yang ingin di edit
        //$datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($IdPribadi);
        return view('datapribadi/edit',['datapribadi'=>$datapribadi]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, DataPribadi $datapribadi)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'namalengkap' => 'required|min:5',
            'namapanggilan' => 'required|min:5',
            'tempatlahir' => 'required',
            'tgllahir' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'golongandarah' => 'required',
            'namaayah' => 'required|min:5',
            'namaibu' => 'required|min:5',
            'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|dimensions:max_width=400,max_height=400,min_width=100,min_height=100'
        ]);
        
        //dd($request->all());
        #untuk mengupdate data yang ingin di edit
        //$datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($id);
        $datapribadi->update($request->all());
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $request->file('avatar')->move('images',$request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName());
            $datapribadi->avatar = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
            $datapribadi->save();
        }
        return redirect('/datapribadi')->with('sukses','Data berhasil diupdate');
    }

    public function delete(DataPribadi $datapribadi)
    {
        #untuk menghapus data
        //$datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($IdPribadi);
        $datapribadi->delete($datapribadi);
        return redirect('/datapribadi')->with('sukses','Data berhasil dihapus');
    }

    public function profile(DataPribadi $datapribadi)
    {
        //$datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($IdPribadi);
        $ptingkatpendidikanmaster = \App\TingkatPendidikanMaster::all();
        $ppekerjaanmaster = \App\PekerjaanMaster::all();
        $phobimaster = \App\HobiMaster::all();
        $pperiodekehadiranmaster = \App\PeriodeKehadiranMaster::all();
        //dd($tingkatpendidikanmaster);

        //Menyiapkan data untuk chart
        $categories = [];
        $data = [];

        foreach($pperiodekehadiranmaster as $pkm){
            if($datapribadi->periodekehadiranmaster()->wherePivot('periode_kehadiran_master_id',$pkm->id)->first()){
                $categories[]= $pkm->bulantahun;
                $data[]= $datapribadi->periodekehadiranmaster()->wherePivot('periode_kehadiran_master_id',$pkm->id)->first()->pivot->jumlah;
            }
        }
        
        //dd($categories);
        //dd($data);
        return view('datapribadi.profile',['datapribadi'=>$datapribadi, 'ptingkatpendidikanmaster'=>$ptingkatpendidikanmaster, 'ppekerjaanmaster'=>$ppekerjaanmaster, 'phobimaster'=>$phobimaster, 'pperiodekehadiranmaster'=>$pperiodekehadiranmaster, 'categories' =>$categories, 'data' =>$data]);
    }

    public function addriwayatpendidikan(Request $request, $iddatapribadi)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        $datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($iddatapribadi);
        if($datapribadi->tingkatpendidikanmaster()->where('tingkat_pendidikan_master_id',$request->tingkatpendidikanmaster)->exists()){
            return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('error','Data Riwayat Pendidikan Sudah Pernah Didaftarkan');
        }
        $datapribadi->tingkatpendidikanmaster()->attach($request->tingkatpendidikanmaster,['tahun' => $request->tahun]);
        
        return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('sukses','Data Riwayat Pendidikan berhasil dimasukkan');
    }

    public function addpekerjaan(Request $request, $iddatapribadi)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        $datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($iddatapribadi);
        if($datapribadi->pekerjaanmaster()->where('pekerjaan_master_id',$request->pekerjaanmaster)->exists()){
            return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('error','Data Pekerjaan Sudah Pernah Didaftarkan');
        }
        $datapribadi->pekerjaanmaster()->attach($request->pekerjaanmaster,['utamasampingan' => $request->utamasampingan]);
        
        return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('sukses','Data Pekerjaan berhasil dimasukkan');
    }

    public function addhobi(Request $request,$iddatapribadi)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        $datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($iddatapribadi);
        if($datapribadi->hobimaster()->where('hobi_master_id',$request->hobimaster)->exists()){
            return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('error','Data Hobi Sudah Pernah Didaftarkan');
        }
        $datapribadi->hobimaster()->attach($request->hobimaster,['intensitas' => $request->intensitas]);
        
        return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('sukses','Data Hobi berhasil dimasukkan');
    }

    public function addperiodekehadiran(Request $request,$iddatapribadi)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        $datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($iddatapribadi);
        if($datapribadi->periodekehadiranmaster()->where('periode_kehadiran_master_id',$request->periodekehadiranmaster)->exists()){
            return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('error','Data Kehadiran Sudah Pernah Didaftarkan');
        }
        $datapribadi->periodekehadiranmaster()->attach($request->periodekehadiranmaster,['jumlah' => $request->jumlah]);
        
        return redirect('datapribadi/'.$iddatapribadi.'/profile')->with('sukses','Data Kehadiran berhasil dimasukkan');
    }


    public function editjumlah(Request $request, $id)
    {
        return $request->all();
    }

    public function deletejumlah($iddatapribadi, $idperiodekehadiran)
    {
        $datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::find($iddatapribadi);
        $datapribadi->periodekehadiranmaster()->detach($idperiodekehadiran);
        return redirect()->back()->with('sukses','Data Jumlah Kehadiran Berhasil Dihapus');

    }

    public function exportExcel() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new DataPribadiExport, 'Datapribadi.xlsx');
    }

    public function exportPdf() 
    {
        $datapribadi = \App\DataPribadi::all();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('export.datapribadipdf', ['datapribadi' => $datapribadi]);
        //$pdf = PDF::loadHTML('<h1>Data Jemaat</h1>');
        return $pdf->download('datapribadi.pdf');
    }
}
```

I tried to call it from my singlepost.blade.php using this code :

```
<img src="{{$post->user->datapribadi->getAvatar()}}" alt="">
```

and the laravel system error :

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function getAvatar() on null
```

How can i solve this error??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: please share your controller 's code

Comment: Seems that there's no datapribadi instance associated with user of the post. Try dd($post->user);

Comment: Try `{{ $post->user()->datapribadi()->getAvatar() }}`

Comment: Please paste the ->getAvatar() function

Comment: @GreenPepper
{{ $post->user()->datapribadi()->getAvatar() }}  
another error
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::datapribadi()

Comment: @QMR
sec, i will edit my post with new Controller

Comment: And if you edit your User Model like this? `return $this->hasMany(DataPribadi::class);` ?

Comment: @Aashishgaba yeah with this code $post->user, there is no datapribadi on that..

Comment: As @OMR said, please share the controller code. And also dd($post->user->datapribadi). If there's no datapribadi associated with that user then you can't access the getAvatar function. That justifies the error statement

Comment: @Kusy
Paste that function to ?

Comment: @GreenPepper
Already did that and still give error
 ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::datapribadi()

Comment: @Aashishgaba dd($post->user->datapribadi) this return null.. yeah, i think the error in relation.. 

I have user from users table that can have many post from posts table and 

each user can have "datapribadi"(personal detail) from datapribadi table (with Avatar Row inside)

Comment: @Aashishgaba ok. i already add the controller code, on the post..

Comment: By controller code, I meant the function or controller which is sending data to the view where you have `<img src="{{$post->user->datapribadi->getAvatar()}}" alt="">`

Comment: Also, get the user id from $post->user and see if there's an entry in the datapribadi table with user_id set to the user from $post->user.

Comment: Nevermind, i got it.
The problem is in User.php

public function datapribadi()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(DataPribadi::class);  
    }

It should be "hasOne". Thank you, guys

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in User.php public function datapribadi() { return $this->hasOne(DataPribadi::class); } It should be "hasOne".